# Synchronize Outlook Calendar in Sharepoint

Tags: calendar, outlook

is it possible to synchronize the Outlook and the SharePoint calendar (both ways)?
So you can see the entries of the Outlook calendar in SharePoint?
It's easy to connect only the SharePoint calendar with Outlook, but this isn't (all) I'm looking for.

(SharePoint 2013 and Outlook 2013 in use)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add SharePoint calendar to Outlook it basically creates a new Calendar in Outlook. In Outlook, in Calendar, the SharePoint calendar is added under Other Calendars. If the check boxes are selected for the SharePoint calendar and your default Outlook calendar, both calendars appear together in Side-By-Side Calendar view.

Make sure you are adding events to the SharePoint calendar and not your personal calendar.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/outlook-help/view-and-update-a-sharepoint-calendar-HA010354986.aspx

Comment: Correct me, if I'm wrong, but this is how to add a Sharepoint calendar to Outlook.
But I want to add the Oulook calendar to Sharepoint. Is this even possible?

Comment: @rereadit i have updated the link

Comment: thanks, this is a nice way to see both calendars in Outlook. Is it possible that I see both calendars (overlayed) in *Sharepoint* ?

Comment: Yes, you can add a new calendar overlay in SharePoint. Select Exchange calendar http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2641729

Answer (score 0):

If you want you might be able to overlay your outlook calendar in sharepoint.
That said it will overlay the personal calendar in sharepoint of the person currently logged into sharepoint.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Overlay-a-SharePoint-calendar-with-a-calendar-from-Exchange-or-SharePoint-4CAEBE59-3994-4A94-9322-B31ABB8A5E9A#__toc341798090

Comment: Can you please add some brief description from the link you provided.